# Problems with gradient in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to estimate the gradient of my graph.

```
#define the function
def gradient(y1,y2,x1,x2):
    gradient = ((y1 - y2)/(x2 - x1))
    y1 = 1.07
    y2 = 1.39
    x1 = 283
    x2 = 373
print('The gradient of this graph is', gradient)
```

All it prints is

```
The gradient of this graph is <function gradient at 0x7fb95096bd30>
```

Comment: You didn't call your function, and your function itself returns nothing (assigning a value to the function name isn't how returning works in Python).

Comment: So how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def gradient(y1 = 1.07,y2 = 1.39,x1 = 283,x2 = 373):
    gradient = ((y1 - y2)/(x2 - x1))
    return gradient
print('The gradient of this graph is', gradient())
```

or

```
x1 = 28
x2 = 373

y1 = 1.07
y2 = 1.39

def gradient(y1,y2,x1,x2):
    gradient = ((y1 - y2)/(x2 - x1))
    return gradient
print('The gradient of this graph is', gradient(y1, y2, x1, x2))
```